# how do i retrieve table id inside mysql

Tags: php, mysql

how do i retrieve table id inside mysql without PHP involved? or is it possible?

```
 $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_timeslot, id_bookslot

     ,coalesce(thera_a, '<a href=\"available.php?id_timeslot='id_timeslot'\" >available</a>') 
     AS thera_a

     FROM ( SELECT t.id_timeslot,b.id_bookslot

      ,MAX(CASE WHEN b.date_book='$search_date' AND b.id_beautician=1 THEN '<a href=\"booked.php?id_timeslot=\">booked</a>' END)     
    AS thera_a
```

from the mysql code:

```
<a href=\"available.php?id_timeslot='id_timeslot'\" >available</a>
```

Comment: wait what? I think we need more information on this. i can't tell what you are asking. what exactly are you trying to accomplish in a general sense?

Comment: I wouldn't ever do this. Querying the db requires PHP (in this case) anyway, so just concat some string together after fetching the record. This is the intention of using a server side language. MySQL was never designed to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use mysql function concat

```
SELECT concat('<a href=\"available.php?id_timeslot=', id_timeslot, '\">available</a>') from Table .....
```